# SQL Case statement returning true although should be false

Tags: sql

I have a SQL statement that is something like this

```
SELECT t1.*
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.COL1 = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN 
            (t1.COL2 = 'val' OR t1.COL3 = 'val' etc) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE etc...) > 0)
        THEN Run same sub query
        WHEN 
            something else
        THEN defaultvalue
    END as brokencase
```

Now, the second WHEN statement above, when run alone, is returning zero. However when it is run here, I am getting a bunch of null values back because that statement is somehow returning true.

So why is the count statement returning zero, but the WHEN statement thinks its true? I have left out a lot of details here for privacy reasons, but this is the general problem.

Comment: Are you saying this: `(t1.COL2 = 'val' OR t1.COL3 = 'val' etc) AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE etc...) > 0)` is returning 0?  If not can you tell us exactly which line is returning 0?

Comment: Its probably not a general problem but a specific problem with your SQL. You should consider creating sample that people can work with  like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5519058/119477)

Comment: @Abe Miessler: Yes that line when run by itself returns zero correctly. But when run in the statement, it executes the WHEN statement as if its not returning zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I see this, the programmer is missing an ELSE or DEFAULT case in their statements.  To find out what scenario you're not capturing, set up a select like this:

SELECT DISTINCT columnTested1, columnTested2, columnTestedX, case statement
FROM blah

Show all the columns being tested, then your case, what you'll see in the result is the combination of columns that are causing your NULL.  You need to capture those in your case statement or you'll continue to *miss* those options

When you test different columns in the different options, you might need multiple else statements to catch them all.  Once you've identified the combination of columns causing you a problem, it becomes dead simple to fix the case statement.

Comment: This answer helped me out the most. I actually did find that when I took out one part of the query it worked, and if I put it back in it was actually falling through without any of the cases working. Whereas I continued to think that it was hitting that case and returning null.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude results that have null values you will have to make sure you are checking for that in your `WHEN` condition.  You haven't specified your `WHERE` clause in your count query so I can't say for sure if this is the problem.  It would look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE ExcludeValue IS NOT NULL
```